# Implementing a category theme using SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.CategoryTheme?

Tags: shapefile, c#, sharpmap

[GitHub page for SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap) has a link for related solution for [CategoryTheme](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.CategoryTheme) without any sample code.  Can someone provide sample code using the SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.CategoryTheme for a shapefile using SharpMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to instantiate `Shapefile` provider, `VectorLayer` and how to assign a theme should be clear. Here are some examples for setting up the theme:

- [`CategoryTheme` with ranges](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.CategoryTheme/blob/master/CategoryThemeTest.cs#L92)
- [`CategoryTheme` with specific values](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.CategoryTheme/blob/master/CategoryThemeTest.cs#L118)

Be sure to update your  repository.